# lmdb: Can I access different named databases in the same transaction?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lmdb

I want to write a lot of data to a lmdb data base with several named (sub) data bases.  I run into the following problem:

- To write to one named data base, I need to open a transaction for this named data base.
- This implies: To write to another named data base, I need to open a different transaction.
- Two write transaction inside the same main data base cannot exist at the same time.
- This implies: I need to commit and close a transaction each time I want to switch from writing to one named data base to writing to another named data base.
- Creating and committing write transactions is a really slow operation.

I rather would like to keep one long-running write transaction for all write operations and commit it once --- when all the work is done.

Is this possible with lmdb (if yes, at which point did I err in my analysis)?

Answer (score 1):

You can open as many named databases within the same write transaction as you like.

So:

- Open write transaction
- Open named databases as required and write to them
- Commit your transaction

As long as you take into account that you can only ever have one write-transaction at a time (read-only transactions are no problem), and that your other transactions will only see the result of your write-transaction once you commit, you can of course have one long-running write transaction.

Comment: The problem with this approach is: Each time I want to write to a different sub-database, I need to commit the current transaction.  This involves lock/unklock operations on disk files and is inherently slow.  My question was whether I can run **all** write operations without the overhead of opening and closing many transactions

Comment: You don't need to commit between writing to different databases. The transaction is valid for the complete database (so all your named sub-databases). You can open as many as you want within the same transaction, and once you're done commit once.

Comment: I thought so as well.  But it didn't work:  Whenever you want to open a sub-data-base, you need to create a transaction for this sub-data base.  That's because of the API: you can't access a sub-data-base except through its own transaction object.  More than one write transactions clash and the process hangs.  This was the reason for me to ask this question...

Comment: I think now that lmdb.open(..., lock=False) solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you err in your analysis at this point

> - This implies: To write to another named data base, I need to open a different transaction.

One transaction handle can be used to open multiple subdatabases in an lmdb environment.

> Note: a single transaction can open multiple databases.
>   [Ref](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/starting.html)